# Setting an output filename using IIB

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

I have an integration that read messages from IBM mQ, thus no filename is created in message environment. I need to assign filename (f.e. ETOS_Message_timestamp.mxl) but not exactly sure how to.

I can access the Message Assembly in java.

guess not much code to show needed

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the file name in the local environment tree using either esql OR java

Below is a sample of ESQL:

```
  SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.File.Directory = '/tmp/FileDirectory'; 
  SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.File.Name = '<<Your file name>>'
```

Below is a sample of Java code:

```
  MbMessage OutputLocalEnviron = new MbMessage(objmsg.getLocalEnvironment()); 
  MbElement outLocEnv = OutputLocalEnviron.getRootElement();
  outLocEnv.evaluateXPath("?Destination[1]/?File[1]/?Directory[1][set-value('Your file name')]");
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the ESQL way.